# Laravel storage link won't work on production

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `storage_path` to save my images and I symbolic my storage folder to `public_html`

```
php artisan storage:link
```

On the local everything works fine, when I upload an image it will upload in storage folder and link of it will appear in `public` folder but since I moved to live host and production mode my images will upload in storage folder but nothing in my `public_html/storage` and I'm not able to get them in my front-end.

## Codes

`/config/filesystems.php`

```
'public' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => storage_path('app/public/'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
  'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

`.env`

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

`controller sample`

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $filename = 'page' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $location = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $filename);
  Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);
  if(!empty($page->image)){
    Storage::delete('images/' . $page->image);
  }
  $page->image = $filename;            
}
```

any idea?

Comment: You're not using a `public` directory, you're using `public_html`. I don't like this strategy. Make a public directory in `public_html` and set the the `url` to `env('APP_URL').'/public/storage'`.

Comment: you need to recreate the sym link on the server, it doesn't transfer with it

Comment: @Ohgodwhy sorry but i'm confused, 1) `Make a public directory in public_html` i do have folder in my `public_html` it's created when i ran artisan command, 2) i did `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/storage',` but nothing changed still i can't get my images

Comment: @ATechGuy how do i do that? i don't have terminal in my host (not sure!)

Comment: Are you really sure you should be using `$image->getClientOriginalExtension();`? That would allow me to store a .php file on your server and execute any code in it.

Comment: there are a few ways to do it, you can run that same command from a route, you can ftp in and some ftp programs will allow you to make a sym link.

Cpanel also would work -> https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9561/29/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-cpanel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## SOLVED

**Thanks for all your helps**, I tried to run `php artisan storage:link` on my server and I found out that my server has disabled `symlink` for security reason.

So I have changed all my image uploading functions to upload images in my `public` folder instead of `storage` folder and now everything is working just fine.

Comment: Uploading to Public isn't recommended and isn't standard Laravel convention.

Comment: @ahinkle uploading to public has no issue whatsoever, if your point is that others can load your assets in their urls and using your sources you're always able to limit assets access from other origin with your code or either with help of cloudflare link protection.

Comment: "Storage" is there for a reason. It's the laravel storage system. Given, why the other answer has more upvotes than your selected answer.

Comment: yes well it depends on hosting/server limitation we're using as well not everything in our hands + nobody is looking for up votes we're here for solutions. best of luck

Comment: @ahinkle what do you suggest to do when we can't use symlinks for some reason?

Comment: @Lamar as I've mentioned use public folder (ie. Public_html) upload your files directly there using public_path()

Comment: I agree, just asking @ahinkle in case he has any other suggestion.

Comment: @Lamar LOL sorry, I just saw notification didn't pay attention to mention :)

Comment: So I was wondering when you say public_html, is it a directory under /storage or you mean the assets directory /public?

Comment: @Lamar it's main directory in shared hosts, it's similar as www/html in vps. It's the directory that your index.php is located

Answer (score 41):

I see that the question has been answered but I want to suggest another solution which i found to be easy.
Go to the route folder `your-app-folder/routes/web.php` and register a new route as follows

```
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

then go to your website `www.example.com/linkstorage` and it will take you to a blank page.
that's it. The storage folder will be create. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: this one is easiest of all, no need to edit path (which may vary in many environment). each time migrate to production server, just need to call this.

Comment: Brilliant!! I don't know why this is not in the official Laravel documentation... i think... Thank you.

Comment: Dosent work for me either.. protocol error

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 You may also create a file (eg, `symlink.php`) in your public directory and add the following lines of code `<?php symlink('/home/your-host-namespace/public_html/your-app-folder/storage/app/public', 
'/home/your-host-namespace/public_html/storage');` you may also adjust the code according to the location of your directory. when done, visit www.your-domain.com/symlink.php, and that should do the trick for you.

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 Try deleting if there any 'storage' folder that has been created inside public folder while development, and run the above route again. Worked for me that way!

Answer (score 22):

Delete folder storage from public and run this command in cron job (one time):

```sh
ln -s /home/public_html/storage/app/public /home/dev5/public_html/public/storage
```

Comment: this worked for me, just that if using Laravel Sail you'll likely need to run : ```ln -s /var/www/html/storage/app/public /var/www/html/public/storage```

Comment: I wrote `Artisan::call('storage:link');` in `routes/web.php` file and run the website then commented this link again in `routes/web.php` file. It solved my issue and created `storage` symbolic link in `public` folder automatically. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

I just encountered this problem, and this is how I fixed it, without the need of SSH'ing into the server or running a CronJob:

For **Laravel 5+** (Haven't tested with lower version)

You may use [`Artisan::call()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) method inside your route/controller to execute artisan commands without using the terminal.

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call('storage:link', [] );
echo $exitCode; // 0 exit code for no errors.
```

Answer (score 10):

I know it is an old thread but we can change it by a little change in Config/filesystem.php

Replace

```
'links' => [
        public_path('/storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

with

```
'links' => [
        base_path('/public_html/storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

[image]

You can check this repository. I have already implemented in it
https://github.com/ali-chaudhry/Laravel-7-Boilerplate-with-Spatie-uuid-Unishrp-filemanager-integeration

Comment: Yes this works on bigrock server thx aklot man

Answer (score 9):

What I did to solve this problem:

1. go inside the project folder using ssh
2. if public folder not exist, create it. If already created, then make sure the storage symlink you created in development been deleted.
3. do `php artisan storage:link`
4. move the storage symlink that created to the public_html folder
5. done.

Comment: I tried tons of solutions. Only this one worked for me!!!

Comment: I was trying to get the url of storage folder. My code was also proper for getting the storage image. But it was not working. I applied this command and checked then it was working. Thanks.

Comment: This solution works, don't forget to do this when moving your project to another server.

Answer (score 7):

**This answer is for those who are still facing issue**

**Step 1**

remove the `storage` link from the `public` folder.

**Step 2**

Give permission to the `storage` folder

```
chmod -R 775 storage/
```

**Step 3**

Create the sym link

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: That worked really well!

Answer (score 5):

change storage_path settings by public_path

```
'public' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => public_path('app/public_html/'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
  'visibility' => 'public',
],

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $filename = 'page' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $location = public_path('app/public_html/images/' . $filename);
  Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);
  if(!empty($page->image)){
    Storage::delete('images/' . $page->image);
  }
  $page->image = $filename;            
}
```

if that does not work, you can try:

```
$path = base_path().'/../public_html/images';
```

Comment: Is this the same /public directory where you put your assets, or is it just a magic folder inside /storage ?

Answer (score 3):

You also can delete your folder storage:link first then open terminal in host and command php artisan storage:link . If your hosting support symlink it will works

Comment: That's a good answer, As I see in my server, the symlink was disabled, so I enabled it, then I ran the command storage:link, but nothing, all links were still 404, then I saw this answer, remove the storage folder from PUBLIC, rerun the cmd, and hoop hhh it worked!

Answer (score 3):

remove storage folder from the public directory
then use this route

```
Route::get("/storage-link", function () {
    $targetFolder = storage_path("app/public");
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder);
});
```

Comment: where should i put this code?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The command `php artisan storage:link` has to be initialized/run again when you start with production on your server. Make sure your webhost provides a SSH access or use a script file with the

```
Artisan::call('storage:link', []);
```

command otherwise. I'm using Laravel v8+ and Livewire.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to upload files and images directly to public_html folder.
change **config/filesystems.php** like this:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path() . '/../public_html/admin-upload',
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/admin-upload',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on shared web hosting and also i had no access to terminal.
this was the Error

> symlink(): No such file or directory

So,
Just create a folder named 'public' in my root (same address with app,vendor,config,... folders)

then i did :

```
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
```

**Because you changed "public" folder's name on production to "public_html" and there is no "public" folder depend on default configs on Laravel 8**
remember set all configs on config/filesystem and ... to default.

after all, if the symbolic was created, you can remove 'public_html' and rename "public" folder to "public_html"!
That's it

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:
Laravel 9.

My application is in a subdomain.

Deleted storage from the public_html folder

Added a route like this to my web.php (Note the absolute path).

```
Route::get('/create-symlink', function () {
    symlink('/home/myusername/domains/mysub.domain.com/myappfolder/storage/app/public', '/home/myusername/domains/mysub.domain.com/public_html/storage');
    echo "Symlink Created. Thanks";
});
```

Went to mysub.domain.com/create-symlink.

That was it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, to solve it, I had to delete the storage of the folder which was already created then I relaunched command.
PHP artisan storage:link

Answer (score 0):

If You want to Run php artisan storage:link and Don't Have Terminal Access
Then You Can do it by creating a Temporary php file example run.php
and Use this Code

```
<?php
echo exec("php artisan storage:link");
```

Also Remember if .htaccess is working disable it temporary i know its not good solution but you can use it to resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

in shared hosts symlink() function is disabled
you can activate it by going to select php version in cpanel
then go to option then disabled function and remove symlink from disabled function

Answer (score -4):

Solution:
Once your application is uploaded to the live server. 
Just check that if you are having any storage folder in public directory.
[Check the folder stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nmMq.png)

Just delete the storage folder from the public directory.

```
[app/public/storage]
```

After that from putty software access your main Laravel project folder, and run this command on live.

Remember to configure your **.env** file APP_URL={your live server ip} and then the below command.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

It will create a new storage link in public folder associated with the **APP_URL** .