# Display Images From Storage Folder in View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7, laravel-storage

When I upload images to a storage folder in my localhost, it works fine. However, when I move my Laravel 5.7 project to shared hosting the images don't appear, and I don't know why.

Thank you for your help.

**Blade**

```php
@foreach ($data as $user)
    @foreach(json_decode($user->name, true) as $images)
    @endforeach
@endforeach
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    @foreach ($data as $user)
        @foreach(json_decode($user->name, true) as $images)
            <div class="item">
                <img src="{{ asset('/slider/images') }}/{{$images}}" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**Controller**

```php
<?php

if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
    foreach ($request->file('image') as $image) {
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(storage_path() . '/slider/images/', $name);
        $data[] = $name;
    }
    $query = DB::table('slider')->insert([
        ['title' => 'lorem', 'alt' => 'lorem', 'name' => json_encode($data)],
    ]);

    return "good";
} else {
    return "null";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try login using ssh and run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

or create `.htaccess` to your root laravel folder and add this code below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and make sure you have proper permission to your `storage` folder.

that could probably helps.

Comment: I run this command in my localhost all it's good but in my shared hosting doesn't show  images

Comment: can you review the access.log/error.log of your server? what does it say against attempts to load an image from your project?

Comment: also "doesn't show images" is vague. Please be more specific. Is it a white page? An nginx error? a web error code i.e 404?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50771337/3240068

Your shared hosting server may or may not allow symlinks. If you run the command and it still does not work, then you have two options, basically.

1) Upload / move / copy images from storage to public;

2) https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads

Create a route and controller that reads and returns images from storage. This is not tested, so do some proof-reading and research, but it should go something like this:

```
// Route
Route::get('storage-asset/{$path}', 'App\Http\SomeController@getStorageAsset');

// Controller
public function getStorageAsset($path)
{
    if (File::exists(storage_path($path)) {
        return response()->file(storage_path($path));
    }

    // If file not found.
    return abort(404)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file (e.g, link.php) inside the public folder and declare the `codes` below.
*make sure to declare your path as is in your app.*

```
<?php
    symlink('../public_html/storage/app/public', '../public_html/public/storage');
```

then, you can visit `your-domain.com/link.php`, and that's it. done