# Laravel Storage Url connection time out in production environment

Tags: laravel

Laravel `Storage::disk('a disk')->url($user->image)` works perfectly fine in localhost with all environments no problem
But on the VPS with Nginx using the Laravel docs .conf file the url is giving connection timeout for `Storage::disk('a disk')->url($user->image)`

I already did

1. storage:link
2. APP_URL= 'vps ip address' (i don't need a domain name yet)
3. config/filesystem.php is fine since it works on my system

If I copy the storage folder to public it works but if there is a symlink to the storage folder it does'nt

Comment: What is the result of `Storage::disk('a disk')->url($user->image);`

Comment: "http://ip/storage/image.png"

Comment: Did you check your public/storage folder?

Comment: Yes i did check public/storage if i copy the storage folder to public it works but if there is a symlink to the storage folder it does'nt

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730143/laravel-storage-link-wont-work-on-production)

According to this, your server might disable the symlink for security reasons, so try to upload your images into the public folder directly. Ex: `public/uploads`

Comment: i have other Laravel projects on the same VPS but they are all working fine so that is not problem